# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.dispatch')

Tags: react-native, redirect

i have this React native component that contains two classes the first has a button that i want it to redirect me to another page it doesn't redirect anything it's just dispatching error . When i try the same function of redirection with the second class it works . Where is the problem please ?

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import {
       TouchableOpacity ,
    View,
    BackHandler,
     Image,
   Text,
    Button,

  Platform,
    ActivityIndicator
     } from 'react-native'; 

      import {connect } from 'react-redux'

  class HeaderBarWebView extends Component{
        constructor(props){

       super(props);
      }

      goCamera(){

        this.props.dispatch(changeCurrentPage("camera"))
        }

     render(){
     return(

      <View>

    <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center',display:  'flex'}} 
       onPress={this.goCamera}>
      <Image
    style={{tintColor:"white" , height:30,
      width:30,marginRight:20}}
    source={require('../resource/img/camera.png')}
     />
    </TouchableOpacity>   

     </View>
             )}}

     class WebviewApp extends Component{

         constructor(props)
         {

       this.state={}
       this.goCamera= this.goCamera.bind(this)
         goCamera(){

      this.props.dispatch(changeCurrentPage("camera"))
                   }
     render()
      {
        return(
        <View style={{flex:1,width:"100%"}}>
                <Button title="Press me" onPress={this.goCamera}></Button>

        <CustomWebView
           ...........................
          />

          </View>
           );
         }
            }

     const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      page:state.router.page,

       camera : state.router.camera

                    })
     const WebviewAp = connect(mapStateToProps)(WebviewApp,HeaderBarWebView)
         export default WebviewAp
```

Here is the error shown

[image: pic]

Comment: You are using react-navigation? , If so, use this.props.navigation.dispatch

Comment: No i am not using react-navigation . Just using router

Comment: Ok then if you are not able to use this.props.dispatch then you are not defining you routes correctly, is not the fault of the component, chack your root router to see if the screen is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind goCamera function with "this", in constructor;

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.goCamera = this.goCamera.bind(this);
}
```